# Making pygame wait for user click/input before proceeding (python quiz game)

Tags: python, pygame

So I am trying to make a game on pygame which would display a vocabulary as a question and three answer choices. And if the user presses the correct answer, their score will go up by one, and the game will move on to the next vocabulary question.

I store my questions in an 2D array called questions[], in each element of the array it holds the questions and answers for each question as [question, correct answer choice, answer choice, answer choice]. So the correct answer is always at index position [i][1]. I do randomize the order in which the answer choices are shown later.

Now my problem is that my game goes through the questions without waiting for user input. The point was that it would wait for the user to click. When the user clicks, then it checks where the user click. The position of the user's mouse will determine which "answer box" the user pressed. Let's pretend the user pressed the first box. The game then compares whether the text stored in that box is correct (i.e the text is the same as questions[i][1]). It displays each question for a split second, and then moves on to the next question and the next question.

But it does not wait for the user to click first. Not even, it doesn't even display the questions long enough for the user to read the question. Is there a way I can perhaps structure the loop or add certain conditions so that the program would display each question until the user chooses an answer, and then add the score and move on to the next question?

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
from random import randint
from pygame import *

pygame.init()
pygame.font.match_font('Courier New.ttf')


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (71, 212, 15)
BLUE = (42, 250, 246)
PINK = (255,102, 196)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
i = 0

size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Spanish Space Quiz") 

done = False

questions = [["Hola", "Hello", "Goodbye", "Cow"],["Amigo", "Friend", "Cat", "Dog"],["Si", "Yes", "No", "Maybe"]]
answerboxes = [[30,300,190,150,BLUE,WHITE,7],[255,300,190,150,YELLOW,WHITE,7],[480,300,190,150,PINK,WHITE,7]]
score = 0
choices = []

def textObject (text, font):
    textWord = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
    return textWord, textWord.get_rect()

def answerbutton(drawbox):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if drawbox[0]+drawbox[2] > mouse[0] > drawbox[0] and drawbox[1]+drawbox[3] > mouse[1] > drawbox[1]:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, drawbox[5],(drawbox[0],drawbox[1],drawbox[2],drawbox[3]),drawbox[6])           
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, drawbox[4],(drawbox[0],drawbox[1],drawbox[2],drawbox[3]),drawbox[6])

    answerTextFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier New",60)
    textWord, textBox = textObject(drawbox[7], answerTextFont) #the text & the "Text box"
    textBox.center = ( (drawbox[0]+(drawbox[2]/2)), (drawbox[1]+(drawbox[3]/2)) )
    screen.blit(textWord, textBox)

def questionbutton(message,x,y,w,h,color):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,(x,y,w,h))

    answerTextFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier New",60)
    textWord, textBox = textObject(message, answerTextFont) #the text & the "Text box"
    textBox.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    screen.blit(textWord, textBox)

while not done:
    screen.blit (backgroundImage, [0,0])
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Courier', 30, True, False)
    text = font.render("SPACE VOCBULARY QUIZ",True,WHITE)
    screen.blit(text, [30, 30])
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Courier', 30, False, False)
    text = font.render("SCORE: ", True, WHITE)
    screen.blit(text, [500, 30])

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if i == (len(questions)): #if user clicks close then done becomes true and game quits
            done = True
            event.type == pygame.QUIT
        for c in range (len(questions)):
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            questionbutton((questions[c][0]),30,150,640,100,GREEN)
            for n in range(3):
                choices.append(questions[c][n+1])
            for r in range(3):
                randomPointer = randint(0, (len(choices)-1))
                answerboxes[r].append(choices[randomPointer])
                choices.remove(choices[randomPointer])
                answerbutton(answerboxes[r][0:8])
            if click[0] == 1: 
                for a in range(3):
                    if answerboxes[a][0]+answerboxes[a][2] > mouse[0] > answerboxes[a][0] and answerboxes[a][1]+answerboxes[a][3] > mouse[1] > answerboxes[a][1]:
                        if answerboxes[a][7] == questions[i][1]:
                            score = score + 1
                            print (score)
            for g in range (3):
                answerboxes[g].pop()           
            i = i+1

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a minute to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). StackOverflow is not s service for writing code, but moreso a means of collaborative troubleshooting. This means, in this case, that it is important to describe what you've tried before now and/or posting a copy of your current code.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an infinite loop in the loop for questions, with the break condition of exiting the infinite loop when mouse is clicked on the answer box.

**Example**:

```
for c in len(range(questions)):
    clicked_on_answer = False
    while True:
        # your code

        if click[0] == 1: 
            for a in range(3):
                if answerboxes[a][0]+answerboxes[a][2] > mouse[0] > answerboxes[a][0] and answerboxes[a][1]+answerboxes[a][3] > mouse[1] > answerboxes[a][1]:
                    clicked_on_answer = True
                    if answerboxes[a][7] == questions[i][1]:
                        score = score + 1
                        print (score)
        if clicked_on_answer:
            break
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, when I run the code, nothing appears on the screen and it there is an infinite spinning wheel. I am not sure why. :/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to restructure the program and better separate the drawing from the event handling and game logic. It should only proceed to the next question if a mouse button is pressed, so check in the event loop `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:` (only one `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event is produced per click), then see if a rect was clicked, increment the score and finally render the next question and choices. Blit the question and choice texts outside of the event loop.

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
# Define the fonts outside of the main loop.
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Courier', 30, False, False)

# Render question and choice text surfaces.
# Create the rects for the choices and set their positions.

while not done:
    # Handle events.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Check if event.pos collides with the correct rect.
            for index, rect in enumerate(rects):
                if rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and choices[index] == correct_answer:
                    score += 1
            # Get next question and choices, render them and update the rects.

    # Draw everything.
    # Blit the question and choice text surfaces at their rects.

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)  # Limit frame rate to 30 fps.
```